# Hive Script, DISTINCT with SUM

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to distinct and then find the count of the teams a player played for in any single season and number of teams he played for. This is tripping me up and ofcourse i have a sample down below(2nd) one. The first ones is my failed attempt

```
SELECT o.id,o.year,COUNT(DISTINCT(o.team)) b JOIN
(SELECT id, year, team FROM batting
GROUP BY id,year,team
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 25) o 
0.id =b.id;



SELECT id, year, team FROM batting
GROUP BY id,year,team
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

produces
[image]

IGNORE the ^A, i think they represent either space or comma, just column seperatpr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the count of teams for each player for each year and order by the count desc,get the 1 row

```
SELECT id, year, COUNT(DISTINCT(team)) FROM batting
GROUP BY id,year
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT(team)) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```